# magento full text search not working on Live

Tags: php, magento

Magento full text search not working

I do following steps

full text search option enable from `system->configuration->catalogsearch`

and

```
 app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resources/Fulltext.php
```

change

```
 $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
```

to

```
 $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND', $like) . ')';
```

but still i not  able to search `fulltext` word exactly match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to change

```
$where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
```

to

```
$where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
```